# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0,y\rightarrow0}\frac{xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}=?$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0,y\rightarrow0}\frac{xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}=?$

Now intuitively(if I am right), when I substitute $x$ and $y$ with zeros I get $\frac{0}{-\infty}$ - which is $0$. I also checked on Wolfram Alpha and solution is $0$.

If this is okay I struggle with formally writing the solution, or is it okay to leave it like this?

--EDIT--

Now I also have to show the existence of partial derivatives at point $(0,0)$

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}=\frac{f(x+0,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=...=0$, is this okay? Same for $y$.

Comment: This is not an indeterminate form and your argument is fine.

Comment: I'd say that is no intuition at all: $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\ln(x^2+y^2)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}xy=0$, therefore the limit of the quotient is $0$.

Comment: Yes on the partial derivative, but in the future ask it as a new question.  We try to keep questions focused here and especially not add new questions to existing ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0 \le \left|\dfrac{xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}\right| = \left|\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2\ln(x^2+y^2)}\cdot \dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{|\ln(x^2+y^2)|}\to 0\implies \dfrac{xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2)} \to 0$$.

Comment: I have edited the post I just have a quick additional question I would appreciate if you could check it :D Also thank you for the answer!

Comment: The substitution is only for you to feel what the answer is, but cannot be considered a valid proof. A proof must be formal. Also, in the proof the $x,y$ can't be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we can also proceed by polar coordinates as follows

$$\left|\frac{xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}\right| =\frac{\rho^2\left|\cos \theta \sin \theta\right|}{\ln (\rho^2)}\le \frac{\rho^2}{\ln (\rho^2)}\to 0$$